# Does C++ support constant arrays of type string?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a programming student in my first C++ class, and for a recent project I did, I was unable to create an array of strings like I could do in C#:

```
string MONTHS[ARRAY_CAPACITY] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
// this yields many compiler errors in C++
```

Is it possible to do something similar in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: what is ARRAY_CAPACITY? How is it declared. What errors (is usually a good thing to say)?

Do you really want an array of `string` (object), versus an array of c-string (array of char)?

Comment: `#DEFINE ARRAY_CAPACITY 12`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you initialise the array in C++ then it doesn't require a size to be set (although it'll accept one), so:

```
 std::string months[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
```

compiles fine with g++ for me and I'd expect it to compile elsewhere too. I expect your errors are due to the lack of `std::` namespace.

Comment: I was missing a colon in my ARRAY_CAPACITY declaration! Figures, as soon as I post here I figure out my problem. Sorry to bother you SO'ers with such an elementary question. Thanks for providing me with the correct syntax!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does:

```
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    static const size_t Capacity = 12;
    std::string Months[Capacity] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May",
                                        "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
                                        "Nov", "Dec" };
}
```

Your errors were probably related to something else. Did you remember to use `std::`? Without knowing, it could be anything. Was `Capacity` the wrong size? Etc.

Note your code wasn't actually a constant array. This is:

```
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    static const size_t Capacity = 12;
    static const std::string Months[Capacity] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April",
 /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^ */                                 "May", "June", "July", "Aug",
                                                    "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
}
```

Also, you don't actually need `Capacity`, as others will show, and you *could* use `const char*` if you'd like, though you lose the `std::string` interface.

Answer (score 5):

The preferred method for an array of constant strings would probably be an array of cstrings,

```
const char* MONTHS[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
```

However, it can also be done with std::strings,

```
const string MONTHS[] = { string("Jan"), string("Feb"), ... };
```

Some compilers may not allow implicit conversion from char* to std::string when you initialize an array with curly braces; explicitly assigning an std::string constructed from a char* will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The syntax you used in the question is correct, as long as the compiler understands that `string` is `std::string` and as long as the number of initializers in between `{}` does not exceed `ARRAY_CAPACITY`.

Of course, if you wanted to have a *constant* array, as the title suggests, you should have declared it `const`. Without `const` your array will have external linkage and cause linker errors if you put it into a header file included into multiple translation units.

```
const std::string MONTHS[ARRAY_CAPACITY] = { "Jan", /* and so on ... */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Visual C++ supports it - I've just done something similar. Not sure about other versions of C++.

Have you included the  library? What is the definition of ARRAY_CAPACITY?

When you say 'unable', do you mean you had compiler/linker errors or something else? Can you provide more details?